# Calculate logarithm in tensorflow not in-place

Tags: python, tensorflow, math, keras

I have the following function (see below).
It takes an (N,8,3) tensor as argument. I need to choose along axis 0 and 2, so I receive a selection with size (N,1,3) from probabilities along axis 1.

I solved that with `tf.random.categorical`.
Sadly this function needs the vector along axis 1 to be calculated with `tf.log(vector)` beforehand.  (I don't see the reason, but that's what the docs say).

Now, this calculates log in-place, so it destroys my argument from outside.

- I can't copy the tensor. `copy = tf.constant(move)` is not possible,
  because *move* is a tensor.
- I can't exp(ln(move)) because I receive NaNs after.
- I can't use Numpy, because it's inside a tf.function. (GPU, but 32bit)

How is it possible to calculate the logarithm not-in-place (or choose from probability without `log(prop)` )  ?

Thank you

```
@tf.function
def convert_to_move(move):
    # copy  = tf.constant(move) <---  this is not supported by tensorflow. 
    # move = tf.math.log(move) <--- this errors if move==0. not direct but recreate with exp. is not possible
    m1 = move[:, :, 0] 
    m2 = move[:, :, 1]
    m3 = move[:, :, 2]
    x1 = tf.random.categorical(m1, num_samples=1)
    x2 = tf.random.categorical(m2, num_samples=1)
    x3 = tf.random.categorical(m3, num_samples=1)

    # move = tf.exp(move)
    # x1 = tf.argmax(movetensors[0], axis=1)
    # x2 = tf.argmax(movetensors[1], axis=1)
    # x3 = tf.argmax(movetensors[2], axis=1)

    r1 = tf.squeeze(tf.one_hot(x1, move.shape[1]))
    r2 = tf.squeeze(tf.one_hot(x2, move.shape[1]))
    r3 = tf.squeeze(tf.one_hot(x3, move.shape[1]))

    p1 = tf.boolean_mask(move[:, :, 0], r1)
    p2 = tf.boolean_mask(move[:, :, 2], r2)
    p3 = tf.boolean_mask(move[:, :, 3], r3)

    k1 = tf.stack([x1, x2, x3], axis=-1)
    k2 = tf.stack([p1, p2, p3], axis=-1)
    return tf.squeeze(k1), tf.squeeze(k2)
```

Comment: What's your tensorflow version? why it would destroy the argument from outside? I have ran your code in both tf1 and tf2, the convert_to_move function has no effect on tensor outside. Could you give more code to reproduce your issue?

Comment: My Version is 2.6.  Im very sure that i had this error, but i cant reproduce it now and im not the one who run to stackoverflow and ask immedietly. There was negative softmax values, and my only explenation / solution was to get rid of the tf.log , but it seems that i made a mistake. im sorry to steal your time, thanks that you tried it !